# outlook vba, convert text in subject line to proper case

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to convert the text in the subject line to proper case. My code is below, when I run it the subject line is erased.

```
Sub ProperCaseSubject()

    Dim myMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myMessage = Outlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    Dim subject As String

    subject = myMessage.subject
    s = StrConv(subject, vbProperCase)

    myMessage.subject = s

End Sub
```

I appreciate any help you could give me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try putting a debug statement and verifying what the value of s is before setting it as subject? Does it work without the propercase conversion?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I added a watch but the value is shown as "". I'm not sure how to add a debug statement to verify the value. This is my first time writing code in outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your code. You are never setting your subject. You initially grabbed the `subject` variable from `myMessage.subject`. The value of `subject` at this point is `""`. I guess you are looking to modify the subject for a mail that is currently open. You may want to go through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223171/outlook-vba-get-details-of-current-active-or-open-email) on how to read Subject from the current selection.

Later you converted to lower case which would return `""`. You are assigning the returned empty string back to `myMessage.subject`.

```
Sub ProperCaseSubject()

    Dim myMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myMessage = Outlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    Dim subject As String

    subject = myMessage.subject ' Problematic line
                                ' You need to input this or capture this   
    s = StrConv(subject, vbProperCase)

    myMessage.subject = s

End Sub
```